# In what circumstances would I need to use Protractor ExpectedConditions to wait for an element

Tags: protractor

I'm new to working with Protractor and I was wondering in what circumstances would you need to use `ExpectedConditions` (example below) when using Protractor. I thought that Protractor automatically determine when an AngularJS page is fully loaded.

```
let EC = ExpectedConditions;
let condition = EC.presenceOf(element(by.id("something"))); 
browser.wait(condition, 10000);
```

Thanks, Eric

Comment: Actually i still use browser.wait a lot even with enabled waitForAngular, you cannot rely 100% on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience working with Protractor, the use of ***ExpectedConditions*** depends on the behavior of the page you are automating. It's mostly used due to failing if the condition doesn't comply in the specified time.

These conditions will also return a promise that you can handle to your liking.

I'll give you a few scenarios so you can understand where to use them.

1. **alertIsPresent()**: This condition will wait till an alert appears.

e.g.: After clicking a button, there will be an alert appearance; however, there's an API call which makes the pop-up take longer and also a small animation, so we want to wait a few seconds and no more than that.

```
// will click on a button  
element(by.id('button')).click();  
// will wait for the condition  
let EC = ExpectedConditions;  
browser.wait(EC.alertIsPresent(), 5000);
```

The following code will wait for 5 seconds after clicking the button, to see if the alert is present, else it will throw an error.

2. **invisibilityOf()**: This condition will wait till the specified element is not being displayed.

e.g.: There's a loader that appears for every single action that is triggered in the page. For this we want to wait till this loader disappears so we can continue with the automation process. By business requirements, this loader shouldn't take longer than 10 seconds.

> This loader locks the whole page, so other elements are not interactable while it is up.

```
// trigger random action on page so loader appears  
element(by.id('button2')).click();  
// will wait for the condition  
let EC = ExpectedConditions;  
browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element(by.id('loader'))), 10000);
```

After clicking a button, we will give a 10 seconds grace for the loader to disappear, else the condition will throw an error.

3. **elementToBeClickable()**: This condition will wait till the specified element can be clicked.

e.g.: The button to the login form is disabled by default, so it can't be clicked unless we complete the username and password textfields. The button being enabled after filling the textfields has a fast animation, either way we want to give it 1 second to complete and check if we are able to click it.

```
// complete both textfields required for the button to be enabled  
element(by.id('username')).sendKeys('User1234');  
element(by.id('password')).sendKeys('Protractor');  
// will wait for the condition and then will click the button
let EC = ExpectedConditions;  
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.id('loginButton'))), 1000);  
element(by.id('loginButton')).click();
```

After completing both textfields, the condition will wait for 1 second for the element to be clickable, if it is, it will procede with the next line and click it. On the other hand, if it doesn't, an error will be thrown.

4. **presenceOf()**: In this case, the condition will check if the element is present in the *DOM* (Document Object Model) but it won't check if the element is visible or not.

e.g.: On a page with a radio button group containing 3 flavors: chocolate, vanilla and strawberry. Depending on which you choose, you will be shown different questions. Developers mentioned that the questions are in the page at all moments, but are hidden due to which radio button is selected at the moment. In this situation, we just want to check that all questions exist in the *DOM*, whether or not they will be shown by a radio button being selected.

```
// check all questions directly, without selecting any radio buttons  
let EC = ExpectedConditions; 
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('question-1'))), 1000);  
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('question-2'))), 1000);  
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('question-3'))), 1000);
```

The time is pretty irrelevant here; nonetheless, using this conditions we will be able to check that the questions, even though hidden, exist in the *DOM*. If one is missing, an error will cut the test immediately.

---

These were a few examples I've had to deal with in the past. The use of the conditions is situational and mostly they are useful when you want to use the existing conditions since they save you the time of building them yourself.

PD: More information can be found in the [Protractor API](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions).

Comment: Thanks Cristian for the thorough explanation!  Just to clarify, would **browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)** work instead of using the ExpectedConditions?

Comment: @Eric27710 In most situations, yes. In the scenarios I described, I had to use **browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)** due to a wrongly done Token API making protractor stuck forever if _Angular Enabled_ stayed **true**.    

Even if you are using **browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true)**, you might find some situations in which you'll need the _expected conditions_, and don't be scared to use them, since you don't need to build anything on them, you'll just be able to see in step by step basis what you are waiting for to happen in the page you are automating.